# Auto-fill controller language has changed in a new form, how do I reset it?

Tags: commcare

I'm working in a form and for some reason the auto-fill controller language (the one that the others auto-fill from) has changed. I've gone back to other forms in the same project and added new questions, they still auto-fill from the English box.

What do I need to change to get back to the standard workflow?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand. When building a form with multiple languages in CommCare, additional language boxes will auto-fill with whatever the default language for the application has been set to. You would need to manually update translations for the other boxes. This is so that if someone forgets to update a translation and deploys the application, the end user would still see some text for that particular question or translation.

Unless what you describe was a recent change, the only other area of CommCare that I know of that auto-fill translations is for User Interface Translations: https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/User+Interface+Translations

As a note, you could more quickly update all translations for a form in Form Builder by handling translations outside of CommCare using the process described in this document: https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Form+Bulk+Translation